# Background image covering everything

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a background image that is covering my content but without (background-size: cover;) it doesn't take up the space. I am working on a bootstrap project, and all my content is stacked at the top of the page in the banner area. I've tried adding height to the page to move content. I've tried adding a div around it and moving around in the body tag. I have been working on the for about 3 hours.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Rambla|Staatliches&display=swap');

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

:root{
    --color-black: #000000;
    --color-white: #ffffff;
    --color-border: #ffffff34;
    --font-staat: 'Staatliches', cursive;
    --font-os:  'Oswald', sans-serif;
    --font-ram: 'Rambla', sans-serif;
}

/* global classes */
.font-staat{
    font: normal 400 18px var(--font-staat);
}
.font-os{
    font: normal 300 18px var(--font-os);
}
.font-ram{
    font: normal bold 18px var(--font-ram);
}

.font-size-40{
    font-size: 40px;
}
.font-size-34{
    font-size: 34px;
}
.font-size-27{
    font-size: 27px;
}
.font-size-20{
    font-size: 20px;
}
.font-size-16{
    font-size: 16px;
}

.bgcolor-black{
    background-color: var(--color-black);
}

/* #global classes */

#header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:1;
    transition: left .5s ease;
}

#header nav{
    height: 100vh;
}
#header .site-title .navbar-brand{
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: var(--color-secondary);
}

#header .nav-link{
    margin: .7rem 1rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-border);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#header .nav-link:hover{
    color: var(--color-white) !important;
}

#header .toggle-button{
    background: none;
    color: var(--color-black);
    position: fixed;
    top: 25px;
    right: 20px;
    border: 1px solid var(--color-border);
}

.toggle-left{
    left: 0 !important;
    width: 1000px !important;
}

/* site-main */

.site-banner .banner-area{
    background: url(https://i.pinimg.com/736x/2a/a1/da/2aa1da060c0dfad146354e0cc06560c2.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.site-banner .banner-area .author{
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.site-banner .banner-area .author .author-img{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    background: url(./20200507_023239272_iOS.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 115%;
    background-position: 15% 20%;
}




@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .toggle-button{
        display: none;
    }
    #header{
        z-index:0;
    }
}
/* #site-main */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Kaija Dunklin</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


</head>
<body>
    
    <!-- header area -->
    <header id="header">
        <div class="row m-0">
            <div class="col-3 bgcolor-black">
                <nav class="primary-nav navbar-expand-md">
                    <div class="site-title text-center text-light py-5">
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand font-staat font-size-40">Kaykay</a>
                        <p class="description text-uppercase font-os"> Kaija Dunklin</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                        <a href="#home" class="nav-item nav-link text-white-50 font-os font-size-16 active">Home</a>
                        <a href="#skills" class="nav-item nav-link text-white-50 font-os font-size-16 active">Skills</a>
                        <a href="#projects" class="nav-item nav-link text-white-50 font-os font-size-16 active">projects</a>
                        <a href="#education" class="nav-item nav-link text-white-50 font-os font-size-16 active">Education</a>
                        <a href="#experience" class="nav-item nav-link text-white-50 font-os font-size-16 active">Experience</a>
                        <a href="#resume" class="nav-item nav-link text-white-50 font-os font-size-16 active">Resume</a>
                        <a href="#contact" class="nav-item nav-link text-white-50 font-os font-size-16 active">Contact</a>
                    
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="toggle-button"><span class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></span></button>
        <div class="social">
            <span class="mr-3"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></span>
            <span class="mr-3"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></span>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- #header area -->
    <main id="site-main">
        <div class="row m-0">
            <div class="col-md-9 offset-md-3 px-0">

                <!-- site-banner area -->
                <section class="site-banner" id="home">
                    <div class="banner-area">
                        <div class="author text-center">
                            <div class="author-img"></div>
                            <h1 class="text-white font-staat font-size-40 text-uppercase py-3">Kaija Dunklin</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                     <section id="skills">
   
                            <i class="fab fa-github-square" ><a href="https://github.com/kaidunklin23">GitHub</a></i>
                        


                    </section>
                <!-- #site-banner area -->
      
                <section id="projects">
                    <div>
                       
                    </div>
                </section>
               
            </div>
        </div>
         <div>
                   
    </div>
    </main>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha256-MAgcygDRahs+F/Nk5Vz387whB4kSK9NXlDN3w58LLq0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="./vendor/typed/typed.min.js"></script>

<script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want with your background image? How should it look like? Can you please explain

Comment: My problem is not the background image but all my content is being put behind it at the top.

Comment: Really sorry, but it seems to be working fine at my end. Your title "Kaija Dunklin" appears on the front of your background image, in the center. Also your menu appears on the left side. Looks quite fine. 
Or maybe I am not getting your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what you are trying to achieve, but I guess I got what you wanted:

I set the background on separate div which I then set the background image to and then with Z-index value on css moved behind other content you may add on your page.

```css
.background-img {
    /*of course with this solution you should remove the previous background image*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/736x/2a/a1/da/2aa1da060c0dfad146354e0cc06560c2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    /* Without z-index the background seems to cover the content*/
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!--I added this empty div to hold the background image-->
<div class="background-img">
</div>
```

I really did not dive that deep to your source files, so I am not sure if this helps, but I hope so